# Problem processing payment after CiviCRM Drupal to Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor

After migrating from Drupal to Wordpress, my payment processor is no longer working.

After having gone to the payment processor I am redirected to the URL:
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn&processor_name=Sagepay.....

The error I get is: You do not have permission to execute this url.

Any help in getting to the bottom of this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stab here, but have you checked the Wordpress Access Control (**Administer > Users and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) > WordPress Access Control**) settings to make sure that Anonymous users have access to the "*CiviContribute: make online contributions*" permission?

Comment: Sadly it is enabled. I've hacked it a little for now by adding 'payment' to the list of allowable arg2's in civicrm.php. I'll up date with the answer once I track to down properly.